# Trigger event based on programmatic change of input field

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm writing a form. There's a section at the end the displays all the values the user has inputted for confirmation.

I'm trying to make it so that each time the user changes an inputted value the corresponding value in the confirmation section changes to match that new value. It's working fine except for in cases where values of one input field change based on changes in another input field.

In other words, it's only capturing changes inputted directly by the user, not programmatic changes. For instance when the user selects a value one dropdown a value in a separate dropdown may be automatically set to a specific value but this does not register as a change -- since the user did not change it directly -- and therefore the new value doesn't show up on the confirmation page.

```
$('input[class*="js-input-"]').change(confirmItem);
$('select[class*="js-input-"]').change(confirmItem);

function confirmItem() {
var changedItem = event.target.className;
var value = $('.' + changedItem).val();
$('.' + changedItem + '-confirm').text(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".js-input").on("change", function(e) {
  $(".js-input-confirm").text($(e.target).val());
}).change();
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/5M89n/